# How to do "has term (with depth)" filter on field of a related field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

i have a content type 'product', and two taxonomy lists 'company' and 'country'.
Country list has one level of depth like:

........
state1
-city1
-city2
........

Each product has a 'company' field. Each 'company' term has a 'country' field.
I'm trying to create a view for 'product', filtering by 'country'.
By adding the relationship "content: Company" i have only "taxonomy term: field_country" filter without depth.
There is a way to filter with depth like "Has taxonomy term (with depth)" ?

I'm on drupal 7

Comment: https://www.google.ae/search?q=drupal+views+filter+by+depth&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=U8QxUvLvO5PwhQeQ8ICwDw#q=drupal+7+views+filter+by+term+depth&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial

Comment: sorry, i've tried to googling a lot, but what i need is different or is little bit more complex...the solution seems to be a sort of relation chain, or multiple relation...

Comment: I'm too interested in this. Haven't found any solution for Drupal 8. Have you solved this issue since then?

Answer (score 0):

You would not require a Relationship, just two Contextual Filters.

Based on your requirements Company would be one Contextual Filter - Content: Has taxonomy term ID and Country would be a second Contextual Filter - Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth).

Comment: I need to expose filters, however Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) don't work. Calling directly the 'Country' vocabulary it give me no result. Only by creating a relationship 'Content : Company' it give me 'Taxonomy term: Counrty (field_company_country)' and so i can filter but without depth.

Comment: Seems like I misunderstand, when you say "Each 'company' term has a 'country' field." do you mean that you have a second taxonomy vocabulary on the 'product' content type called 'country'?

Comment: I mean that i have a vocabulary called 'Company' and a vocabulary called 'Country' each 'Company' term has an extra field called "Country" that is a Term Reference field.

Answer (score 0):

In D7, you can only do that with the node table (the content).

If you want to have a working solution for every entity of your system, you have to use [this module](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index).

Once installed, don't forget to rebuild the index of your entities, then, in views, you'll have the possibility to add a new relationship ('Taxonomy Entity Index: Taxonomy terms on User') and a filter with depth ('Taxonomy Entity Index: Has taxonomy terms on User (with depth and indexed in taxonomy_entity_index)').

Comment: The OP is not talking about user entities, but nodes. Answers should be tailored for the question being asked.